# add manifest file to jar with gradle

Tags: java, gradle, jar, manifest

How to add manifest files in jar files?

```
plugins {
        id 'java'
        id 'application'
}

application {
        mainClassName = 'com.Main'
}

jar {
        from "MANIFEST.MF"
}

sourceCompatibility = 11
```

when I try to execute jar, I get following :

> % java -jar tmpApp.jar
>   no main manifest attribute, in tmpApp.jar

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here’s how you can generate an appropriate manifest file in the `jar` task of your build:

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': application.mainClassName
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a custom file for the manifest:

```
jar {
    manifest {
        from 'MANIFEST.MF'
    }
}
```

You can even create a mixture of both:

```
jar {
    manifest {
        // take the existing file as a basis for the generated manifest:
        from 'MANIFEST.MF'
        // add an attribute to the generated manifest file:
        attributes 'Main-Class': application.mainClassName
    }
}
```