# Generate MANIFEST.MF using Spring Boot and Gradle

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, manifest.mf

I need to add the following headers to the *MANIFEST.MF* file using Gradle and Spring Boot:

- Name
- Specification-Title
- Specification-Version
- Specification-Vendor

Is there a way to configure the Gradle build process to read these values from *settings.gradle* and *build.gradle* and write them to the *MANIFEST.MF* file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing them to the manifest file is described here:  [add manifest file to jar with gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53902452/add-manifest-file-to-jar-with-gradle)

To populate these values from `settings.gradle` and `gradle.properties`, consider the following:

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id "idea"
    id "java"
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Specification-Title': gradle.ext.jonesVar
        attributes 'Specification-Version': bibibi
    }
}
```

settings.gradle

```
gradle.ext.jonesVar = "jones"
```

gradle.properties

```
bibibi=3
```

The result from `./gradlew clean build` gives `build/libs/tmp.jar` containing this manifest:

MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Specification-Title: jones
Specification-Version: 3
```

If you need to do this for the `bootJar`, use `bootJar {` instead of `jar {` in your `build.gradle`.